# deploy struts app on jboss

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, struts

I'm working through some struts tutorials, and here's one of the ones I'm using:
http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-login-page-example-1.html

I downloaded the "source + lib" link at the bottom of that page, I copied the Example2 folder from the zip to my webapps folder under tomcat, and everything works as advertised.

However, when I try to take this same Example2 folder and copy it to my jboss 4.2.3 default\deploy folder, it doesn't work.  Sorry for such a newbie question, but just wondered if anyone had any advice.

Here's the beginning of the error trail from the console:

```
9:37:57,968 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Packages waiting for a deployer ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@ae05c37c { url=file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/Example2/ApacheLicense.txt }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/Example2/ApacheLicense.txt
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258850277875
  lastModified: 1258850277875
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@2fc10fd3 { url=file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/Example2/WEB-INF/classes/com/vaannila/ApplicationResource.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/Example2/WEB-INF/classes/com/vaannila/ApplicationResource.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258850277875
  lastModified: 1258850277875
  mbeans:
.
.
.
```

So maybe I need some different configuration for deploying a struts app in Jboss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application needs a `.war` extension, even when doing an "exploded" deployment. Rename the `Example2` directory to `Example2.war` (i.e., you will end up with `C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/Example2.war`).