# struts2 application on jboss

Tags: java, jboss, struts

This is a bit of a continuation of [deploy struts app on jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777339/deploy-struts-app-on-jboss), but it's different enough that I felt it warranted a new question.

In the other question, I was working with struts, but now I'm working with struts 2. 
The tutorials [here](http://www.vaannila.com/) are broken up into struts tutorials and struts2 tutorials.

What I'm finding is that I need to have JAVA_HOME set to point to a jdk6 or the struts 2 samples won't work.  So in eclipse, I added another JBoss Server to my JBoss Server View (I'm using JBoss tools) and made it use jdk1.6.

My question is, is this normal? Does struts 2 require jdk6?

[EDIT]
The stack trace is huge, I'm pasting the first part of it below:

```
2009-11-22 05:13:42,625 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
2009-11-22 05:13:42,890 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil] Added default resource bundle 'org/apache/struts2/struts-messages' to default resource bundles = [org/apache/struts2/struts-messages, com/opensymphony/xwork2/xwork-messages]
2009-11-22 05:13:43,093 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] Loaded [BUILDER] {PackageConfig Name:struts-default namespace: parents:[]}
2009-11-22 05:13:43,203 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory] Loading validator definitions.
2009-11-22 05:13:43,281 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor] new I18nInterceptor()
2009-11-22 05:13:43,281 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor] new I18nInterceptor()
2009-11-22 05:13:43,296 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor] new I18nInterceptor()
2009-11-22 05:13:43,328 DEBUG [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] Loaded [BUILDER] {PackageConfig Name:convention-default namespace: parents:[{PackageConfig Name:struts-default namespace: parents:[]}]}
2009-11-22 05:13:43,500 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.Exception: Could not load invoker/war/WEB-INF/classes/org/jboss/invocation/http/servlet/InvokerServlet$GetCredentialAction.class
2009-11-22 05:13:43,500 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:745)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,500 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:148)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,500 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:295)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,500 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:277)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:52)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:200)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
2009-11-22 05:13:43,515 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3722)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Struts 2 doesn't require Java 6 but Java 5 only (and can even be [backported to Java 1.4](http://struts-2-developers.blogspot.com/2008/08/backporting-struts-2-to-jdk14-using.html) but this is another story).

That said, according to the trace you provided, it seems that the convention plug-in is trying to mess with other elements deployed in the server, `invoker/war/WEB-INF/classes/org/jboss/invocation/http/servlet/InvokerServlet$GetCredentialAction.class` in your case, it found a class that it thinks is an action. This is actually a well known problems with Jboss 4.2.3.GA and the convention plug-in 2.1.6. Quoting Chris Vogel in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg86142.html) that faced the same problem (with Weblogic):

> In case you haven't figured it out, I'll tell you what I have learned.
>   Struts/XWorks scans for `Action` classes and does this by scanning directories
>   it is given by the class loader, not just by looking at JAR files.  The
>   `PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder` that you see in your stack trace makes a
>   call to the `getResources()` method of the current thread's context class
>   loader, which returns back directories in the class path for that class
>   loader.  That call, for WebLogic, actually returns back the base directory
>   of the WebLogic domain.  The `ClassFinder` class then scans all the
>   directories returned back from the `getResources()` method, which for WebLogic
>   includes every directory of the domain, and looks for `Action` classes. If it
>   finds a class that has a super class, it tries to load that super class and
>   this is where we actually see our exception.  I'm wondering if JBoss's class
>   loader is doing a similar thing. `ClassFinder`, if it can't find the class
>   creates an exception and then prints the stack trace and does nothing else
>   with the exception.  We are going to modify the `ClassFinder` class to not
>   print the stack trace.

AFAIK, there are two solutions:

- deploy on JBoss 5 since its classloading policy seems to be more orthodox *or*
- use the version 2.1.3 of XWork, the exception should be logged at a debug level with this version.

PS: I've successfully reproduced the behavior you describe (with a JDK 6), I find the same trace in my logs, but this doesn't seem to prevent the application from working (as I wrote, XWork's developer only changed the logging level in version 2.1.3). Is this what you observe too?

Comment: Yes, I observe the same thing, the example seems to work ok. So I guess it's not hurting anything to run under jdk1.5, right? We just get the annoying trace.

Comment: No, it's not hurting anyone. The trace should be logged as debug actually which is what XWorks 2.1.3 is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the Struts 2 page](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/index.html), only Java 5 is required.  I haven't used Struts 2 in a while, but I did use it with Tomcat + Java 5 a few years ago and didn't run into this problem.  What exception do you get when you're not using Java 6?

Comment: I pasted the stack trace from the server.log file.  Looks like the problems start with "Could not load invoker/war/WEB-INF/classes/org/jboss/invocation/http/servlet/InvokerServlet$GetCredentialAction.class
2009-11-22 05:13:43,500 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:745)"